# installing NUnit from commandline

Tags: .net, nunit

If i issue the following statement:

```
C:\tmp> dotnet new nunit
```

I get something like (translated from italian):

```
There are no models corresponding to the input.
[follows a list of the available models]
```

I found a way to install NUnit on per-project basis with:

```
dotnet add package NUnit --version 3.12.0
```

but this doesn't help here because I need it to create a project, that is *before* the project is there. On the opposite, it seems that "add package" just adds NUnit to an existing project.

dotnet core version: 2.1.202

Comment: Which version of the .NET Core SDK do you have installed? (Run `dotnet --version` to check)

Comment: dotnet --version gives: 2.1.202

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of available project templates on your machine via `dotnet new -l`. Then if there is no nunit package shown in this list, you should be able to install it via `dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template`. Additional info can be found here https://github.com/nunit/dotnet-new-nunit